# Why I am unable to change this checkbox if i use data to restore textbox values beside to it

Tags: jquery

Hi  As stated in the Question i am unable to uncheck/check the textbox..
Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Uehnh/1/
Here is my HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox'><span>Text1</span><input type='text'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox'><span>Text2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox'><span>Text3</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='radio'><span>None of all</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The below code is not allowing me to uncheck or check the checkbox..Actually this is intended to restore the previously cleared data of textbox..

```
 $('.humble').live('change',function()
 {
    var th=$(this);
    var input=th.closest('td').find('input[type="text"]');
    if(th.prop('checked',false))
    {
        input.data('text',input.val());
        input.val('');
    }
    else
    {
        input.val(input.data('text'));
    }
 });
```

and here is the fiddle with complete code http://jsfiddle.net/Uehnh/1/
I am trying to restore the text with previous text using data property.. But here i am unable to check the first checkbox.. This is not allowing me to do..
Please check and let me know errors..

Comment: It's not being checked because your code is preventing it. Honestly, it's hard to make sense of the code. Can you explain how it's *supposed* to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the checked property to false in your conditional statement.  Maybe that was not your intention.

On this line:

```
if(th.prop('checked',false))
```

Did you mean:

```
if(th.prop('checked') == false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but I *think* I understand what you're trying to do. If the radio button is checked, it should deselect all of the checkboxes and clear the input, right?

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$("input:radio").change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
        $("input:checkbox").attr("checked", false);
        $("input:text").val("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As others already mentioned you got the if condition wrong. Please use -

```
if (th.prop('checked') == false)
```

Also, the code you have put together will not work correctly in many cases. Such as unchecking any checkbox checks the radio button even if other checkboxes are checked or entering and clearing the text box when no other checkboxes are checked etc.

I have updated it to work the way, I think, you want it to work - take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uehnh/17/).